# Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ProtectedData' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am getting a runtime error when trying to use System.Security's crypto code. I added a reference to System.Security and everything looks good but I am getting this error: "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ProtectedData' does not exist in the current context"

here is the code that is throwing the error.

```
public static string EncryptString(SecureString input, string entropy)
    {
        byte[] salt = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(entropy);
        byte[] encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ToInsecureString(input)),
            salt,
            DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }
```

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 12):

You need to add a using statement for `System.Security.Cryptography` and you need a reference to `System.Security.dll`. From your question it appears you just added the reference and not the using statement.

Instead of the using statement you can also fully qualify the references like this:

```
byte[] encryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(
            Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ToInsecureString(input)), salt,
            System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to install the NugGet package System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.