# The name 'ProtectedData' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm following [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh487164%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article for storing secure data in the app. But when I use the ProtectedData class I get this error:

```
The name 'ProtectedData' does not exist in the current context
```

Searching found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455442/compiler-error-message-cs0103-the-name-protecteddata-does-not-exist-in-the-c) question that says I need to add a reference to `System.Security.dll` in order to make it work.

I'm new with Windows Phone/C#/Visual. How do I add that reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx

> To Add a Reference in a C# or Visual Basic Project
>
> 1. On the menu bar, choose File, Open.
> 2. Navigate to your solution or project.
> 3. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project node, and then choose Add Reference.
> 4. Specify the references to add, and then choose the OK button.

You will find System.Security under Assemblies -> Framework. Then you will have to add a using statement in your class

Comment: Links can expire, you should post relevant details here.

Comment: When I open the Assemblies -> Framework section I get the following message: "All of the Frameowork assemblies are already referenced. Please use the Object Browser to explore the references in the Framework".  Clicking Browse the folder Programs\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE is open but I do not find any file named System.Security.dll